# Connect Spark streaming to a SDN

Tags: apache-spark, monitoring, sdn, mininet

I am new in world of network. I would like to know how can I connect spark streaming to SDN network to monitor the network. I want to use mininet and POX as a SDN controller to simulating a SDN network. I have already installed spark and scala(and python) on my mininet VM. However I could not find any good tutorial or documentation based on both SDN and Spark. Please let me know what should I do. (Even by a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little general. However you should capture the packets using tcpdump or tcpprobe, then try to analyze them using spark in streaming way. For example predicting something. After that use your result in any part of your controller you want like like Pox.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any link to help me?

Comment: @Reza: Just search "Streaming in Apache Spark". It would be a good thread to start. ;)